# How to filter Just Number in string, then how to add with another number if the number is start with zero

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm beginning in PHP or cakephp.

I have a case, when I want to get *Just* The Number in a code which type is string,

This is example string:

***PR00006757***

I want to get the number *00006757* without *PR*

I already tried using:

```
$code = filter_var($this->request->data['Price']['code'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
pr ($code); exit;
```

then I get result `"00006757"`,

But I want +1 that result,
to be `"00006757 + 1" = 00006758`,

But in reality, the result after I add 1 ( + 1) the result is `6758` not `00006758`.

How do I get the answer formatted this way?

Comment: `6757 + 1 = 6758` try using [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) `$your_new_value = str_pad($your_new_value, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: Will this string always have `0000` **4 zeros** like in **PR00006757** or its variable like PR00086757, PR00286757 ?

Comment: @bansi : I already try using str_pad, but, no difference the result is 6758... I don't know wheter I'm wrong..

Comment: check the answer [here is a demo](https://eval.in/515303)

Comment: @Kanudo: the string not always 4 zeros, some times can be 5 zeros, et cetera...

Comment: looked like 8 char value to me, so used 8 `0s` to pad

Comment: If you look at my answer you will see that if you use strlen then the PHP will add the correct number of 0s, no matter if it's 4, 5, or 6.

Comment: @bansi : i want the value is not hard code.. can i ?

Comment: @DillonGilmore : I'm already try your code, to use strlen to count, but, it's count not just zeros, but count all number, i want just zeros number which count...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you are getting is correct as adding 1 automatically converts `$code` to integer type. You should use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to pad the integer value you get by adding 1 to make it back to string of the required length.

```
$code = filter_var($this->request->data['Price']['code'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$code +=1;
$code = str_pad($code, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); //convert to padded string
print_r ($code);
```

Edit: [Demo Here](https://eval.in/515303)

Edit 2:
Added auto detection of the length

```
$code = filter_var($this->request->data['Price']['code'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$len = strlen($code); // store the length of the code
$code +=1;
$code = str_pad($code, $len, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
print_r ($code);
```

[Demo Here](https://eval.in/515318)

Comment: your code is true, but, how to automatic detect how many number, can you change 8 to variable which declare how much zeros is ?

Comment: nice to know it worked for you. accept an answer if your problem is solved. it will help others in future.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. Using filter_var is the correct way to grab the number you want. There isn't going to be a way to alter the way that PHP does basic addition. Your best chance is to identify the padding on the number and add that padding back after addition occurs. Here is an update to your code that could help.

```
$code = filter_var($this->request->data['Price']['code'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$len = strlen($code);
$newcode = $code + 1;
str_pad($newcode, $len, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

After testing with your example input I received: "00006758".

Comment: I already try but the result is 0000006758, zeros is 4, i think being six is because $len is not count just zero, but all number..  how to count just zero number ?

Comment: I'm sorry, your  answer is true, I'm wrong in write sintax.. thanks a lot :))

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example

```
<?php
$str_code = 'PR00006757';
$code = filter_var($str_code, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$code +=1;
$num_padded = sprintf("%08d", $code);
echo $num_padded;
```

Comment: thank you very much, your answer also true, you're try with a different way but the result is no difference... :))